# Wildcard redirect for subdomains and URI

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache2.2

I have a problem with create pernament (301) redirect in apache:

I have 2 domains:

   `olddomain.com` with many subdomains

   `newdomain.com`

and I want to do redirect like:

if user enter on `http://anysubdomain.olddomain.com` should be redirected to `http://anysubdomain.newdomain.com`

if user enter on `http://olddomain.com/something` should be redirected to `http://newdomain.com/something`

if user enter on `http://olddomain.com/different/index.html` should be redirected to `http://newdomain.com/different/index.html`

if user enter on `http://example.olddomain.com/ex/index.html` should be redirected to `http://example.newdomain.com/ex/index.html`

I don't know how I should set this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName olddomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect all of your requests from the old domain to the new one, I would use the following.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*\.)?olddomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It matches both the subdomain and request URI and merges them with the new domain. If there is no subdomain, it proceeds to match the request and will redirect without a subdomain.